# How to bind stored procedure columns from complex type to existing Model of MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Can we map the complex type of stored procedure to existing Model classes of Asp.MVC.

Comment: Code first or Database first?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich, Thanks for the reply, DataBase First.

Comment: Which version of EF do you use?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich, Ef 5 and Mvc 4

Answer (score 0):

Right click in model browser, and select update model from database, from dialog window under stored procedures select the stored proc you want to add, entity framework will automatically create a complex type for you.
I hope this helps.